# picking object using mouse click in direct3d (managed directx)

Tags: directx, direct3d

basically I want to pick an object using mouse click in direct3d (managed directx) C#.
I need to transform 2D point to 3D point. After googling, I have found that, I can use picking 
or ray. here is an example of using ray
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203905.aspx

my problem if I implement ray is I can't find GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject in direct3d.
If there is another solution please tell me.

Update:

here is what I have done:

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        int x = e.X;
        int y = e.Y;
        Vector3 nearsource = new Vector3((float)x, (float)y, 0f);
        Vector3 farsource = new Vector3((float)x, (float)y, 1f);

        nearsource.Unproject(device.Viewport, device.Transform.Projection, device.Transform.View,device.Transform.World);
        farsource.Unproject(device.Viewport, device.Transform.Projection, device.Transform.View, device.Transform.World);
        Vector3 direction=nearsource-farsource;
        direction.Normalize();
        }
```

The problem is the farsouce matrix has NaN value

Answer (score 0):

Managed DirectX has been deprecated for a long, long time.  I would suggest using a better supported API like SlimDX.

A little googling revealed [this thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/558254-slimdx---picking/) which seems to be what you want in SlimDX.